# Upon Submitting a Button, Replacing RatingBar with a TextView?

Tags: java, android

I have a Ratings Bar that allows users to vote.  I want them to select the star total on the bar, hit a button to submit, and upon submitting , the Ratings Bar is replaced by a TextView that says something like "Thank you for voting!"

How can I do this in Java code?

Also, for bonus points, is there a quick way to make this a transition. Maybe the textview fade in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setVisibility` for visible/invisible the layout or in your case `RatingBar` and `TextView`

Into your XML file add the `RatingBar` an `TextView`. initially set the textview visibility `GONE`.

on press the submit button add this code:

```
textViewobject.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ratingBarobject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```